# How to pass the data from controller to my view in codeingiter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a method in my controller which returns some data. I currently just echoing it in my controller Now i want to pass that data to my view. I want that my code is displayed in view in table But Some how its now working Please review my code and help me:

this is the controller:

```
public function index()
{
  $loginarry = $this->data['attendances'] =  $this->attendance_m->join_data();

  $logoutarry =$this->data['attendances'] =$this->attendance_m->second();

  //var_dump($total);
  $timeduration=0;
  $login_i=0;
  $logout_i=0;
  //var_dump($loginarry);
  //        echo ("@@@@<br/><br/>");
  //var_dump($logoutarry);
  echo ("Attay LEngth = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
  while(true)
  {
    if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
      break;

    if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
    {
      echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");
      $login_i++;
      continue;
    }
    if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
    {
      echo ("Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<br/>");
                    $logout_i++;
      continue;
    }
    //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

    //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time
    if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
    //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
    {
      echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");
      $login_i++;
      $timeduration += 10;
      continue;
    }
    if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
    //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
    {
      echo ("Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<br/>");
      $logout_i++;
      $timeduration += 10;
      continue;
    }

    //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
    if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
    {
      echo ("Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<br/>");
      $logout_i++;
      $timeduration += 10;
      continue;
    }

    echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data);
    echo (" and Duration = ".((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U')) ."\n<br/>");

    $timeduration += ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
    $login_i++;
    $logout_i++;

  }
  echo ("Total Duration = ".$timeduration. " second(s) " );
  echo"<br>";
  echo("Total Duration = ".$timeduration/'3600'."Hours ");

  $this->data['attendance_dropdown'] = $this->attendance_m->get_emp_list();
  $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/attendance/index';
  $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);

}
```

The Code:

```
<?php
        $loginarry = $attendances;
        $logoutarry =$attendances_logouts;
        $timeduration=0;
        $login_i=0;
        $logout_i=0;


        //echo ("Array Length = " . count($loginarry)." & ".count($logoutarry)."\n<br/>");
while(true)
{ 
    if( $login_i >= count($loginarry) && $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
        break;

    if( $logout_i >= count($logoutarry))
    {
        echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");
        $login_i++;
        continue;
    }
    if( $login_i >= count($loginarry))
    {
        echo ("Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<br/>");
                    $logout_i++;
        continue;
    }
    //echo( "******* ".(new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') . " **** ".(new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U'). "\n<br/>");

    //check if next login time is smaller then current logout time - if so skip current login time
    if($login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
    //if( date_diff(date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data), date_create($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data)) > 0 )
    {
        echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout : -----------------\n<br/>");
        $login_i++;
        $timeduration += 10;
        continue;
    }
    if( (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U') > (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') )
    //if( date_diff(date_create($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data), date_create($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data)) > 0 )
            {
        echo ("Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<br/>");
                    $logout_i++;
                    $timeduration += 10;
                    continue;
            }

    //if more logout entries then skip to last logout entry
    if( $login_i < (count($loginarry)-1) && $logout_i < (count($logoutarry)-1) && (new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i+1]->date_data))->format('U') < (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i+1]->date_data))->format('U'))
    {
        echo ("Login : ----------------- and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data."\n<br/>");
                    $logout_i++;
                    $timeduration += 10;
                    continue;
    }

    echo ("Login[".$login_i."] : ".$loginarry[$login_i]->date_data." and Logout[".$logout_i."] : ".$logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data);
    echo (" and Duration = ".((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U')) ."\n<br/>");

    $timeduration += ((new DateTime($logoutarry[$logout_i]->date_data))->format('U') - (new DateTime($loginarry[$login_i]->date_data))->format('U'));
    $login_i++;
    $logout_i++;

}
    echo ("Total Duration = ".$timeduration. " second(s) " );
    echo"<br>";
    echo("Total Duration = ".$timeduration/'3600'."Hours ");


        ?>
```

[image: output]

Comment: try `print_r($attendance_dropdown)` before loop to check you are getting values or not

Comment: @DishaV. I want to print the echo statments in my view

Comment: The Echo statements i have done in controller @DishaV.

Comment: @DishaV.  my dropdown is working its the other data thats not working

Comment: whatever you set in *controller* by `$this->data['yourvariable']` becomes your variable in *view*

Comment: Okay yeah i just got that now thanks @DishaV.

Answer (score 2):

Basic overview of communicating data to a view in CodeIgniter.

#### Your Controller

Create or fetch your data with your controller (simplified example below).

```
<?

Class MyController extends CI_Controller {

    /**
    * Some method I use
    */
    public function index() {

        $data = array(
            'variable_one'   => 'value one',
            'variable_two'   => 'value two',
            'variable_three' => 'value three',
            'variable_four'  => 'value four'
        );

        $this->load->view('my-view', $data);

    }

}
```

#### Your View

And then that data would be accessible in my view like so:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some Sample CI View</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><? echo $variable_one; ?></h1>
    <h2><? echo $variable_two; ?></h2>

    <p><? echo $variable_three; ?></p>
    <p><? echo $variable_four; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you're having issues accessing that data in your view, then it's time to start debugging your code to ensure the data you're delivering exists and is in the format you expect it to be in.

Comment: i have updated the question u can see the output at last i want that in table but my in my view i can't do this can u please help me